# RStudio View() fails

Tags: dplyr, view, rstudio

When i use `View()` to display variables An error window pops up:

[image: test]

The error text is not visible.

The only thing I know is that this happened after I run code below:

```r
library(dplyr)
top_marker2.interactions <- cluster.markers.interations %>%
      group_by(cluster) %>%
      slice_max(n = 2, order_by = (avg_log2FC))
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you try to `View()` in R itself (not using Rstudio) what happens?

Comment: @Phil , I convince it caused by Rstudio, because there is no error when i use util::View().

Comment: The error text seems like mojibake. What OS are you running on? Is it localized to some language? Also, what RStudio version are you using? Is it reproducible?  Can you post a small and complete repro, *with data*, so we can try your steps exactly?

Comment: I don't see what can be done about this. I'd just point to filing an issue with RStudio on their GH repo, with a clear provision of your computer specs.